# How To Modify A Matplotlib Histogram's Output To Create New Modified Histogram (Without Losing Sync)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to python, I would like to know how to take a calcualted histogram, and modify the output to create a different graph.

Right now I am showing histogram with two data sets in it (fails and successes)

[image]

What I would like to do, is convert the two histogram bars into a % chance of success measurement

This is the code generating this graph...

```
def GetCol(inData, col=None, equals=None):
    if( equals is not None ):
        sub_index = inData[col] == equals
        return inData[sub_index]

    elif( col is not None ):
        return inData[col]

    else:
        return inData   

# Creates and returns a fig with histogram comparies col values - using cols shared by success and failed features
def GetHistogram_Success_Vs_Failure(success, failed, binCount=20, xlbl='', ylbl=''):
    fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(1, 1)

    n, bins, patches = ax1.hist([failed, success], bins=binCount, align='left', color=['red','blue'], label=['Stopouts','Winners'])    

    ax1.set_xlabel(xlbl, fontsize=18)
    ax1.set_ylabel(ylbl, fontsize=18)
    ax1.legend(loc='upper right')   

    return fig, ax1

# get the data
data = pd.read_csv("D:\\python\\Quant testing\\Candle Body Experiment\\CandleBodySignal_EA.csv")

#replace spaces with '_' and all to lower case
data.columns = [col.replace(' ', '_') for col in data.columns]

success = GetCol(data, "Closed_In_Favor", 1)
fail = GetCol(data, "Closed_In_Favor", 0)

title = "AUDUSD 6 Hour Data 2015-2018"

measureAtCol = "Candle_Body_As_ATR(100)_PCT"
colLabel = "Candle Body Percentage of ATR"

fig, ax1 = GetHistogram_Success_Vs_Failure(success[measureAtCol], fail[measureAtCol], 80, colLabel, "Num Trades")

plt.xlim(xmin=-20, xmax = 300)
tick_spacing = 20
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(tick_spacing))
plt.xticks(fontsize=12)
plt.yticks(fontsize=12)
plt.title(title)
plt.show()
```

I understand we can play with the return values of the histogram

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)

n, bins, patches = ax1.hist([failed, success], bins=binCount, align='left', color=['red','blue'], label=['Stopouts','Winners'])

#try play with the histogram outputs
successSpread = n[0] - n[1]
ax2.plot(successSpread)
```

How do I keep my modified data in context with the x axis?

As you can imagine if I plot successSpread the data will be 'unsynchonized' to the original histogram because it is missing the x data points.

Thanks very much!

Comment: I want to know how to get the bin x, y values from the histogram so I can format the data into something like successSpread.

Comment: Let me rephrase: Why is `ax.plot(bins[:-1], successSpread)` not what you want?

Comment: Because successSpread was just a basic example for me to extract data from the hist and have a go at manipulating it. I would like to get the bin dimensions, and turn it the values into a % success chance based off the x value. So I need the count of both success and fail for each hist bar set, and then do the percentage calculation and create a new histogram out of that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't actually want to plot a histogram at all. Instead you want to use two histogram's values and calculate something different from it.

```
bins = np.linspace(min(success.min(),failure.min()), max(success.max(),failure.max()), binCount)
nsuccess, _ = np.histogram(success, bins=bins)
nfail, _ = np.histogram(failure, bins=bins)

chance = nsuccess/(nsuccess+nfail)
plt.bar(bins[:-1], chance)
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I am still confused with the bins output. It is an array of very high floats. This example will at least give me a foundation to work with. Thanks for your knowledge.

Comment: You may create the bins yourself. I updated the answer.